# Using a FlatList with scrollToEnd

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two issues when using a FlatList (that both work with a ListView).

I have a list that is displayed via a display property for each item and then checked in my FlatList like so:

```
<FlatList
  ref='flatList'
  data={this.state.dataSource}
  enableEmptySections
  renderItem={({item}) => item.display && <Text>{item.text}</Text>} />
```

When I change the display property, it doesn't display however. This worked fine in the ListView setup.

My second problem is that scrollToEnd is firing an undefined error on "this._listref" which is within the scrollToEnd function. I pass no parameters to it.

```
setTimeout(this.refs.flatList.scrollToEnd, 0)
```

My questions are, how do I update the data in my array for the list so it changes in the list, and the second question is how do I fix the scrollToEnd error?

**Update 1:** (data removed, not needed anymore)

**Update 2:** Problem ONE solved, the list needs "extraData" comparison to see if it updates. The fixed edition:

```
<FlatList
  ref='flatList'
  data={this.state.dataSource}
  extraData={this.state}
  enableEmptySections
  renderItem={({item}) => item.display && <Text>{item.text}</Text>} />
```

It's a bit convoluted, but I believe extraData acts as a comparison to see if anything in that data set updates. If so, re-render. That problem is solved.

***"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._listRef')" still not fixed***

**Update 3:** Scroll function works IF taken outside the setTimeoutfunction

**Update 4:**

Setting the initial data array

```
  this.state = {
    dataSource: pageService(state.params.page),
    cursor: 0
  }
```

Setting display as true:

```
  renderNextModule() {
    let newCursor = this.state.cursor
    if (newCursor < this.state.dataSource.length-1) {

        newCursor++
        let newSource = this.state.dataSource
        newSource[newCursor].display = true
        this.setState({
            dataSource: newSource,
            cursor: newCursor
        })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is the shallow equal in FlatList deciding not to re-render? I'll update with a section of my data

Comment: First problem solved, updating

Comment: Updating again, this seems to be specific to putting it in a wrapping "setTimeout" function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this._listRef` is undefined because `setTimeout` calls the function and sets its context (this) to null.

As a workaround, you can actually use a wrapper function (here with ES6 syntax) :

```
setTimeout(() => this.refs.flatList.scrollToEnd(), 0)
```

Regarding your 1st problem, I don't think you're solving it the right way.
You were right that it uses a shallow comparison, but you might not need the `extraData` prop.

Are you mutating your array directly? How are you updating the `item.display` property?

---

For your 1st problem,
Replace this line

```
let newSource = this.state.dataSource
```

By this

```
let newSource = this.state.dataSource.slice()
```

In JavaScript, arrays are copied by reference, which means that you were not cloning the array but mutating it ; and as `FlatList` is efficient (and this is for every `PureComponent`), when you want to re-render it (by setting the state like you did), it does a `===` comparison on its old and new props to see if anything changed.

As you were mutating the old array, 'oldArray === newArray', so it was deciding to not update again.

This was a bit concise and fast but you can read more about why you need to create a new array with `.slice()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084515/how-does-shallow-compare-work-in-react). This is true for arrays and objects in JavaScript.

Comment: The array is a state value, so I'm using setState to change it. The initial value is pulled from another function "pageData(pageNumber)" with a return. I update the item.display property via a setState as well. I will update with code

Comment: I had forgotten to bind my scrollToBottom...which fixes the this problem

this.scrollToBottom = this.scrollToBottom.bind(this)

Still interested in hearing about how you might re-render the area though (if you see a problem in the solution above)

Comment: Added a solution and explanation :)

Comment: (you can hopefully remove the `extraData` prop, now)

Comment: Thanks, I will test that out! I thought react did some magic and returned the value, rather that passing the reference

Comment: Sure :) please note that passing the reference is the JavaScript behavior, it's not directly related to React

Comment: This does work, I don't need extraData for comparison anymore

Comment: Anybody have any idea why the setTimeout is necessary? My list does not scroll predictably, If the time is less than a second it does not react the end of the list and stops in random places.

Answer (score 2):

Its work for me

```
data={this.state.messages}
ref = "flatList"
onContentSizeChange={()=> this.refs.flatList.scrollToEnd()}
```

Answer (score 0):

in case of function component.

```
let flatList = React.useRef(null);
```

and in your FlatList component

```
<FlatList
  ref={flatList}
  onContentSizeChange={()=> flatList.current.scrollToEnd()}
  ....
 />
```