# If redux updates a nested component but a PureComponent is passed it's parent as a prop, will the PureComponent rerender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In `redux` if your `action`/`reducer` updates the value of `foo.bar` and your connected component's `mapStateToProps`is `(store) => { foo: store.foo }` and then passes `foo={foo}` to a `PureComponent` child. The child won't rerender when `foo.bar` changes? That's why they recommend keeping things as flat as possible?

Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions:

1. Generally, when does a `PureComponent` instance update?
2. Is the `PureComponent` component instance updating in this example?

Question #1: `PureComponent` does a shallow comparison of props in `shouldComponentUpdate`. What this means is described well in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084515/how-does-shallow-compare-work-in-react). To summarize, a shallow comparison checks for equality of reference rather than equality of value. So, if `lastProps.myObj` and `nextProps.myObj` are both references to the same object, a shallow comparison evaluates to `true` even if `lastProps.myObj.foo` and `nextProps.myObj.foo` are not equal.

Question #2: If you have mutated `state.foo`, so that it's the same object with a changed value, then a shallow comparison will return a false negative. The complicating factor here is that your example uses Redux. You say that a Redux reducer has changed `state.foo`. One of the first [rules](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#handling-actions) of Redux reducers is that they *don't mutate* state or props. They return a new state. When state is an object, they make a copy of the object and apply the change to the copy. If you are honoring the reducer contract and updating the state without mutating it, then you have changed the reference. In that case, the `PureComponent.prototype.shouldComponentUpdate` should return `true`.

```
// create an object
var foo = {bar: 'bar'};
// make a copy of the object 
var bar = Object.assign({}, foo); 
// both objects look the same, i.e. have the same property with an equal value 
foo.bar === bar.bar // -> true 
// but they are not the same object so the shallow comparison evaluates to false
foo === bar // -> false
```

So if the `PureComponent` instance is not updating when `state.foo` has changed, I would review the reducer that changes `foo` and make sure the update is not a mutation.

Comment: So a reducer that only updates `a` in `foo.bar.baz.a` would create new objects for `baz`, `bar` and `foo` so that they are new references? And it would go all the way up to the top level key? Would you also create a whole new state reference? What about references for `foo.bar.qux`? Thank you!

Comment: The Redux docs answer this question: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#updating-nested-objects.