# How does React shallowCompare work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

React documentation states that

> shallowCompare returns true if the shallow comparison for props or
>   state fails and therefore the component should update.

So, if is understand correctly, if there is no state in my component and i know there are no changes in the props keys, this code

```
let shallowDiff = Object.keys(this.props).filter((item) => {
        return this.props[item] !== nextProps[item];
});
return shallowDiff.length !== 0;
```

should return the same as the react comparison. But it doesn't. If there are no changes, my code correctly returns an empty array, whereas react returns true. I am trying to understand this behavior and searching a way to search the problem-key, but i just do not get it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084515/how-does-shallow-compare-work-in-react

Comment: Read it before, but the Problem is the same - the code provided by me should do exactly that, and it does, but react does not. So, what does react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> shallowCompare is a legacy add-on. Use React.PureComponent instead.
>   https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/shallow-compare.html

If there are no changes in state or props, shallowCompare returns false. And of course, when there are changes, shallowCompare returns true, and proceeds with the re-render of the Component.

But if you have a deeply nested object, shallowCompare will not be able to tell that the nested objects have updated/changed.

You either write your own function to check if the object has changed, or you can use a very naive method to check for changes if the **ORDER** of the properties is **NOT** important.

```
JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
```

I personally don't recommend using the shallowCompare or React.PureComponent because the use case is too narrow. If you have a complex object, neither function is effective. If your function works for you, then use it.