# Why React hook useEffect runs endlessly?

Tags: reactjs

I created a project with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app),
and I am trying React hooks,
in below example,
the sentence `console.log(articles)` runs endlessly:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import {InfiniteScroller} from "react-iscroller";
import axios from "axios";
import './index.less';

function ArticleList() {
    const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getArticleList().then(res => {
           setArticles(res.data.article_list);
            console.log(articles);  
        });
    },[articles]);

    const getArticleList = params => {
        return axios.get('/api/articles', params).then(res => {
            return res.data
        }, err => {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }).catch((error) => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
    };


    let renderCell = (item, index) => {
        return (
            <li key={index} style={{listStyle: "none"}}>
                <div>
                    <span style={{color: "red"}}>{index}</span>
                    {item.content}
                </div>
                {item.image ? <img src={item.image}/> : null}
            </li>
        );
    };

    let onEnd = () => {
        //...
    };


    return (
        <InfiniteScroller
            itemAverageHeight={66}
            containerHeight={window.innerHeight}
            items={articles}
            itemKey="id"
            onRenderCell={renderCell}
            onEnd={onEnd}
        />
    );
}

export default ArticleList;
```

Why is it?How to handle it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHLjh.gif]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite loop in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

Answer (score 6):

React useEffect compares the second argument with it previous value, articles in your case. But result of comparing objects in javascript is always false, try to compare [] === [] in your browser console you will get false. So the solution is to compare not the whole object, but articles.lenght

```
const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    getArticleList().then(res => {
       setArticles(res.data.article_list);
        console.log(articles);  
    });
},[articles.length]);
```

Comment: The problem with this method, is that it raises the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` lint error.

Answer (score 2):

This is a gotcha with the React's useEffect hook.

This kind of similar to how Redux reducers work. Every time an object is passed in as the second argument inside of a useEffect array, it is considered a different object in memory.

For example if you call

```
useEffect(() > {}, [{articleName: 'Hello World'}])
```

and then a re-render happens, it will be called again every time. So passing in the length of the articles is a way to bypass this. If you never want the function to be called a second time, you can pass in an empty array as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply because you cannot compare two array (which are simply) objects in JavaScript using ===. Here what you are basically doing is comparing the previous value of articleName to current value of articleName, which will always return false. Since

> That comparison by reference basically checks to see if the objects given refer to the same location in memory.

Here its not, so each time re-rendering occurs.
The solution is to pass a constant like array length or if you want a tight check then create a hash from all element in the array and compare them on each render.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with an array objects.  I found just passing [array.length] as the second argument did not work, so I had to create a second bit of state to keep up with array.length and call setArrayLength when manipulating the array.

```
const = [array, setArray] = useState([]);
const = [arrayLength, setArrayLength] = useState(array.length)

useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios.get(// whatever you need);
            setArray(result.data)
        };
        fetchData();

    }, [arrayLength]);

const handleArray () => {
   // Do something to array
   setArrayLength(array.length);
}
```

There is a deep comparison utilizing useRef that you can see the code [here](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-github-profile/commit/56e0019a310d060fac7fedf2ba6518fcabfbe389).  There is an accompanying video on egghead, but it's behind a paywall.

Answer (score 0):

**How to make it stop running infinitely:**

Replace your `useEffect` hook with:

```js
// ...

useEffect(() => {
    getArticleList().then(res => {
       setArticles(res.data.article_list);
        console.log(articles);  
    });
},[JSON.stringify(articles)]); // <<< addition

// ...
```

**Explanation:**

Before we understand why it runs infinitely or why we did that addition to stop it, we must understand 3 things:

1. Arrays are [JavaScript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#objects).
2. JavaScript compares objects based on reference, not value. Meaning:

```js
const arr1 = [];
const arr2 = [];

console.log(arr1 === arr2) // false
```

- `arr1` and `arr2` are not equal because their references are different (they're 2 different instances). The same would be true if each was equal to `{}`, because those are also objects.

3. React re-runs hooks when a value in the dependency array changes. It does a comparison of the old value and the newly set value.

Why the hook is running infinitely:

- [remember] React re-runs the hook when an item in the dependency array changes. A new instance of `articles`, which is a part of the dependency array, seems to get created (in `res.data.article_list`) and set to `articles` (through `setArticles`). This new instance is not equal to the older one because [remember] JavaScript compares objects based on reference not value. This causes the hook to re-run infinitely.

Why using `JSON.stringify()` stops it from running infinitely:

- Using `JSON.stringify()` converts to a string, which is a [primitive type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#primitive_values), and is compared based on value (not reference). If the content of `res.data.article_list` is the same, then React compares the old stringified version of it with the new one, sees that they're the same, and doesn't re-run the hook.

---

#### Extra: Why using `JSON.stringify(arr)` in the dependency array is better than `arr.length`:

Doing `arr.length` returns a number which is a primitive value. JS doesn't compare primitive values by reference, it compares them by value. I.e. `0 === 0 // true`, so React won't re-run it if `arr.length` doesn't change, , **even if the array content did change**.

So if we have `articles = ['earth is melting']` and then we set a new value to `articles[0]` like `articles = ['earth is healing']`. It will think it's the same and will not re-run the hook, because both `articles.length`s evaluate to `1`.

```js
['earth is melting'].length === ['earth is healing'].length // true
```

Using `JSON.stringify(arr)`, on the other hand, converts the array to a string (e.g. `'[]'`).

```js
"['earth is melting']" === "['earth is healing']" // false
```

So `JSON.stringify(arr)` will re-run `useEffect` every time the actual content OR length of the array changes. Meaning that it's more specific.