# useEffect props callback function causing infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, eslint, create-react-app, react-hooks

I have a problem very similar to this - [How do I fix missing dependency in React Hook useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-do-i-fix-missing-dependency-in-react-hook-useeffect).

There is one key difference - I am passing a fetch function to a child component to be called from [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), so I can't simply move the function into the body of the effect. The fetch function is re-created every render and causes an infinite loop. I have other local component state that I want to cause the effect to fire.

I basically have a Container Component and a Presentational component. MyPage is the parent of MyGrid and sets up all the redux state:

```
const MyPage = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const items= useSelector(selectors.getItems);
  const fetching = useSelector(selectors.getFetching);
  const fetchItems = opts => dispatch(actions.fetchItems(opts));

  return (
    <>
      {fetching && <div>Loading...</div>}
      <h1>Items</h1>
      <MyGrid
        items={items}
        fetchItems={fetchItems}
        fetching={fetching}
      />
    </>
  );

}

const MyGrid = ({ fetchItems, items, fetching }) => {

  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0);
  const take = 100;
  const [sorts, setSorts] = useState([]);

  // when query opts change, get data
  useEffect(() => {

    const options = { skip, take };
    const sortString = getSortString(sorts);
    if (sortString) options['sort'] = sortString;
    fetchItems(options);

  }, [fetchItems, skip, sorts]);
```

In "MyGrid" "skip" and "sorts" can change, and should make the effect fire.

> "fetchItems" is re-created everytime and causes an infinite loop. This
>   is my problem.

Now, the eslint react-hooks/exhaustive-deps rule is making me put fetchItems in the dependency list.  I have prettier setup to autofix on save which makes it worse.

I know the Container/Presentational pattern is out of style with hooks, but it works good for my situation - I may allow swapping out MyGrid for MyList dynamically and don't want to repeat all the redux stuff in each child component.

I tried to [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), but eslint just makes me put all the same dependencies in it's dependency array parameter.

Is there a way other than disabling the eslint rule

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways, you can make it work.

**Firstly**, using `useCallback` for fetchItem like

```
const fetchItems = useCallback(opts => dispatch(actions.fetchItems(opts)), [dispatch, actions]);
```

**Secondly** using `dispatch` directly in child component

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
 useEffect(() => {

    const options = { skip, take };
    const sortString = getSortString(sorts);
    if (sortString) options['sort'] = sortString;
    dispatch(actions.fetchItems(options));

  }, [dispatch, actions, skip, sorts]);
```

Comment: Why does the dispatch function has to be passed as second param of the useEffect hook?

Comment: @PeeJee it doesn't, but my eslint/prettier puts it in there for me!

Comment: What on earth is useDispatch? Trying to call useDispatch results in undefined.

Comment: @Tyk useDispatch is a function exposed by react-redux.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize this was specific to react-redux. I was trying to learn more about how useEffect() works in general.