# useEffect and watching state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to setState of items on render using a function call and then **watch the items state for changes to cause re-render if they change.** Passing a reference to the object keys as per the suggested answer does not seem to change anything. I am trying to do this using the hook useEffect(). getCart() is an function to retrieve data from localStorage. Code:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setItems(getCart());
}, [items]);
```

I am getting an error "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render."

I understand how I am causing an infinite loop by effectively changing the items state on render and then this causes a re-render and so on. How would I get around this, is this possible using useEffect? Thanks.

Edit: Code that edits the localStorage

```
export const updateItem = (productId, count) => {
   let cart = [];
   if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
            cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        }
        cart.map((product, index) => {
            if (product._id === productId) {
                cart[index].count = count;
            }
        })
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite loop in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

Comment: I have tried the methods in this answer and it has not solved the issue. To be clear I want the component to re-render when the items state changes, which can be triggered by a user.

Comment: Do you need to call `setItems` inside of `useEffect` **every time** when `items` change?

Comment: Anytime you call setItems() and change the state the component will re-render, just like changing state without hooks using setState(). useEffect is only really need if you are trying to introduce side effects on mount, unMount, or re-render. You may need to clarify what “changed by the user” means exactly in terms of your code. You need to call setItems when you want a re-render, it’s as simple as that. Honestly, you may not even need useEffect at all, but nots clear with what has been provided so far.

Comment: @goto1 I do yes.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselskySo would it be better to not use useEffect and use a lifecycle method?

Comment: @CaeSea what updates the cart? Ideally, show the code that does it

Comment: @goto1 If a user updates a quantity of an existing cart item

Comment: So why not just call `setItems` there? Whatever function/handler handles this action.

Comment: code that updates localStorage moved to question**

Comment: Yes as @goto1 suggested whatever is handling the change to cart  or similar, call setItems() there. Also put the code into the question, not the comments.

Comment: @goto1 this function is within a separate file and imported

Comment: So why are you using `useEffect` with the `setItems` inside of it? How do you even know when it should be called when you're updating `localStorage` in the function above, which will not trigger `react` to rerender

Comment: BTW, setting local storage is a perfect use of useEffect() as that is a side effect.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I understand what you are saying and will take a look now to try and solve this issue. I am following a tutorial and this is my first time using hooks. I think the video may have skipped over something.

Comment: You need to rethink this a little bit. if you want to use `setItems`, then I'd suggest calling that `hook` from whatever is calling `updateItem`... The way you're using `useEffect` is incorrect, so you need to create handler that will call both `updateItem`, then get items from local storage, then call `setItems`... Don't do `setItems(getCart())` inside of `useEffect` unless you specify an empty array as a dependency so that it only calls `setItems` once to get cart items after it renders, then you have something else that will update your `items` state

Comment: @goto1 Thank you for your help. In the end I created a new function that called setItems() and called it after each call of updateItem. Makes much more sense, could you put your comment as an answer so I could mark it as correct?

Comment: @CaeSea sure, thanks. Glad you were able to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the solution is to move the `setItems` call out of `useEffect` and call it somewhere else along with the `updateItem` function that saves/updates data in `localStorage`:

```js
// cart.js
export const updateItem = (productId, count) => {
  // see implementation above
}

// App.js
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const cartItems = getCart()
    setItems(cartItems)

  // pass an empty dependency array so that this hook
  // runs only once and gets data from `localStorage` when it first mounts
  }, [])

  const handleQuantityChange = (data) => {
    // this will update `localStorage`, get new cart state
    // from `localStorage`, and update state inside of this component

    updateItem(data.productId, data.count)
    const currentCart = getCart()
    setItems(currentCart)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {...}
      <button onClick={() => handleQuantityChange(...)>
        Add more
      </button>
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

This way, calling `setItems` is fine since it will only get triggered when the button gets clicked.

Also, since `useEffect` takes an empty dependency array, it will no longer cause the `maxiumum update depth exceeded` error as it will only run once to get the initial state from `localStorage` as soon as it renders, then this component's local state will get updated inside the `handleQuantityChange` handler.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an array inside `useState`, you need to make sure the array has a different reference every time its value changes.

You can try this in the console:

```
a = [1, 2, 3] // a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a         // b = [1, 2, 3]
a.push(4)     // a = b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b === a       // true
```

Notice `b` is still equal to `a` even if the values inside `a` change. What happens is `React.useState` and `React.useEffect` uses a simple `===` to compare old to new state. To make sure it sees the a different array every time, use the rest operator to copy all the contents of a into b, like so:

```
a = [1, 2, 3] // a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [...a]    // b = [1, 2, 3]
a.push(4)     // a = [1, 2, 3, 4], b = [1, 2, 3]
b === a       // false
```

If you do this, `useEffect` will only be called if the data is really different.

Another thing you should be careful is to not call `setItems` inside `useEffect` as an effect of `[items]`. You should put the result of `getCart()` in another state variable.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'items' from the dependency array. This way it will fetch the items from local storage on the first render only (which is what you want). Any other update to items should be done by the user and not triggered automatically by every re-render.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setItems(getCart());
}, []);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that when items is changed by an action by the user the component does not re-render which is what I want

Comment: @CaeSea Try `useEffect(() => {}, [items]);`

Comment: You can use multiple useEffect-hooks in the same component. For your case (which I don't really see the point of), you can add an empty useEffect function with items in the dependency array as @Baruch point out.