# How to update the state immediately in React functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, components

I am new to React and I am very confused about the lifecyle of a functional component.
Let's say I have many inputs of type: checkbox, a, b, c and d. Their values are a, b, c and d.

```js
const OnBoarding = () => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState({
    a: false,
    b: false,
    c: false,
    d: false
  });
  
  const [allCheckedItems, setAllCheckedItems] = useState([]);
  
  //Write function that pushes checked value to state array when clicked
  const onChecked = e => {
    setIsChecked({
      ...isChecked,
      [e.target.value]: e.target.checked
    });
    const all = Object.keys(isChecked).filter(function(key){
      return isChecked[key] === true;
    });
    console.log("all items that are TRUE : " + all);
    setAllCheckedItems([all]);
    console.log("allCheckedItems : " + allCheckedItems);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(isChecked);
  });
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I have a functional component with a state whose type is an **object** with many properties, all booleans, like so:

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState({
  a: false,
  b: false,
  c: false,
  d: false
})
```

I have an other state that is an **array**, let's call it **allCheckedItems**, that is supposed to be an array of all the keys of **isChecked** set to true.

```
const [allCheckedItems, setAllCheckedItems] = useState([]);
```

With a function onChecked, when a checkbox is checked, it's value in the **isChecked** object sets to **true**.

I call useEffect() in which I wrote a filter function to filter all properties that are true. All the properties set to true are store in an array called **"all"**.

My problem comes when I have to update the state of the array **allCheckedItems**. If I write in the useEffect hook:

```
setAllCheckedItems([all]);
```

I get an infinite loop. If I write it in my **onChecked function**, whenever I click on a checkbox, the state of allCheckedItems that I log in the console is LATE of one click.
Like, I click to check "a" and it logs:

```
[]
```

Then I click on "b" and it logs:

```
[a]
```

Then I click on "c" and it logs:

```
[a, b]
```

I would like that when I check a box, both states update and that allItemsChecked logs all items checked immediately... 
Can someone explain to me this behavior? It has given me headaches for days now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite loop in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the `useEffect` hook gives you an infinite loop is because useEffect is triggered after every render when it is not supplied with the second argument. This is stated on the official react [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) for react hooks, and that the component will skip the applying of the effect if the values within the second argument have not changed.

While calling `setAllCheckedItems()` within your `useEffect()` can work if we set `[isChecked]` as the second argument of `useEffect()` (which will ensure that the effect will only be applied if the values of `isChecked` has changed),

```
useEffect(() => {
  setAllCheckedItems([all]);
}, [isChecked]);
```

I would recommend you to reduce the complexity of the code by simply calling `setAllCheckedItems()` at your `onClick` event of your checkbox, since it is to be run everytime the checkbox is checked. You can refactor the `onChecked` method such that `setAllCheckedItems()` is not reliant on the `isChecked` state.

```
const onChecked = (e) => {
  // get current checked state, and update it with the checkbox values
  const updatedChecked = {
    ...isChecked,
    [e.target.value]: e.target.checked
  }
  // update isChecked state
  setIsChecked(updatedChecked);
  const all = Object.keys(updatedChecked).filter(function(key){
    return updatedChecked[key] === true;
  });
  // update allCheckedItems state
  setAllCheckedItems([all]);
}
```

As you can see, we have created a copy of the `isChecked` state, and update the copy with the new values. In addition, we use that copy to return the keys that are checked. After which, we update the respective states.

Comment: Thanks. I already called the setAllCheckedItems in my onChange event of my checkbox, in the function called onChecked, as you can see. I still see the array empty when I first click, and then one step behind, all the time

Comment: @Jasmine yes, I understand. But you can definitely modify your logic such that `setAllCheckedItems()` is not reliant on the `isChecked` state.

Comment: It worked! Although, I have no idea why. But thanks!

Comment: @Jasmine glad to help! setting of state is asynchronous, that is why the state does not get updated immediately. To overcome this problem, I created a copy of the state at the start of the method, and carry out the necessary logic, before updating the `isChecked ` and `allCheckedItems ` states with the new values.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot!