# React.StrictMode: SetState function in useEffect is run multiple times when effect is run once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

The output of the code below when oldRunIn is `undefined` is as expected when the effect is triggered:

> Effect is running
>
> setState is running

However, the next time useEffect runs with the state variable `runInArrow` defined, which is referred to as `oldRunInArrow` in the setState function the output is:

> Effect is running
>
> setState is running
>
> setState is running
>
> setState is running

How is it possible that the effect runs only one time but the setState runs 3 times?

```
const [runInArrow, setRunInArrow] = useState<mapkit.PolylineOverlay[] | undefined>(undefined);


useEffect(() => {
      const trueRunIn = settings.magneticRunIn + magVar;

      const boundingRegion = region.toBoundingRegion();
      const style = new mapkit.Style({
        lineWidth: 5,
        lineJoin: 'round',
        strokeColor: settings.runInColor,
      });
      const newRunInArrow = createArrow(boundingRegion, trueRunIn, style);
      console.log('Effect is running');

      setRunInArrow(oldRunIn => {

        // This runs too many times when oldRunIn aka runInArrow is defined

        console.log('setState is running');
        if (oldRunIn) map.removeOverlays(oldRunIn);
        return newRunInArrow;
      });
      map.addOverlays(newRunInArrow);
  }, [magVar, map, mapkit, region, settings.magneticRunIn, settings.runInColor, settings.showRunIn]);
```

To understand why I'm using a function to set state see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152888/how-to-read-and-modify-a-state-in-useeffect-iaw-exhaustive-deps-lint-rule)

---

Edit:

This is strange. if I remove `if (oldRunIn) map.removeOverlays(oldRunIn);` it works as expected. However if I change it to `if (oldRunIn) console.log('oldRunIn is defined');` it still runs multiple times. I'm thoroughly confused.

`if (oldRunIn) map.addAnnotations([]);` does not run multiple times.

`if (oldRunIn) console.log('test');` does run multiple times.

This runs multiple times (6 times per use effect) always:

```
  setRunInArrow(oldRunIn => {
    console.log('setState is running');
    console.log('test');
    return newRunInArrow;
  });
```

This does not run multiple times:

```
  setRunInArrow(oldRunIn => {
    console.log('setState is running');
    return newRunInArrow;
  });
```

---

Edit 2:

Reproducible example. Click the button. You don't even need to have `if (oldState) console.log('Old state');` you can just put in 2nd console.log and it will change the behavior.

```
import { FunctionComponent, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const Test: FunctionComponent<> = function Test() {
  const [state, setState] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined);
  const [triggerEffect, setTriggerEffect] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect is running');
    setState(oldState => {
      console.log('setState is runnning');
      if (oldState) console.log('Old state');
      return 1;
    });
  }, [triggerEffect]);

  return <>
    <button onClick={() => setTriggerEffect(triggerEffect + 1)} type="button">Trigger Effect</button>
  </>;
};
```

---

Edit 3:

I've reproduced this by putting this code into another nextJS project. I'm guessing it has to do with nextJS.

---

Edit 4:

It's not NextJS. It's wrapping it in React.StrictMode. Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/intelligent-hugle-nkgcz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). Why?

---

Edit 5:

As the answer pointed out the issue is due to StrictMode intentionally running code twice. It should not run useReducer twice per the docs (this is an issue with "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps" from my other question). Here is a UseReducer demo, try with and without StrictMode. It also runs twice. Seems like it needs to be pure too:

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-hugle-nkgcz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';

function reducer(state, data) {
  console.log('Reducer is running');
  if (state) console.log(state);
  return state + 1;
}

export const Test = function Test() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, 1);
  const [triggerEffect, setTriggerEffect] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({});
  }, [triggerEffect]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setTriggerEffect(triggerEffect + 1)} type="button">
        Trigger Effect
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

const Home = () => (
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Test></Test>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

export default Home;
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple working snippet, as the code shown it's not obvious why this is happening.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: There must be something else going on because I cannot reproduce this with a simple example.

Comment: I added a reproducible example, also I should mention I'm using nextJs

Comment: Your reproducible example seems to be working normally here: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-browser-63pof?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I just saw the same... I'm going to try putting in nextJs and see if it does the same. Just putting that into my index.tsx causes it to run twice.

Comment: Adding the reproducible component to another nextJS problem does the same thing.

Comment: I posted a sandbox. @JLRishe, the problem is React.StrictMode - adding that to your example causes it to happen. I added a sandbox to my question at the end.

Comment: Just curious, what syntax is this? `useState<mapkit.PolylineOverlay[] | undefined>(undefined);`
Is this TypeScript or something?

Comment: @7iiBob Yes, it's TypeScript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you've figured out, this is happening when you use React strict mode, and it is intentional.

As noted in [this article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/react-strict-mode/):

> ## It runs code TWICE
>
> Another thing that React Strict Mode does is run certain callbacks/methods twice (in DEV mode ONLY). You read that right! The following callbacks/methods will be run twice in Strict Mode (in DEV mode ONLY):
>
> - Class component constructor method
> - The render method (includes function components)
> - setState updater functions (the first argument)
> - The static getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle
> - The React.useState state initializer callback function
> - The React.useMemo callback
>
> > Checkout [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xvv55893mp) which logs to the console in hook callbacks and class methods to show you that certain things happen twice.
>
> React does this because it cannot reliably warn you against side-effects you do in those methods. But if those methods are idempotent, then calling them multiple times shouldn't cause any trouble. If they are not idempotent, then you should notice funny things which you should hopefully be able to notice and fix.
>
> > Note that useEffect and useLayoutEffect callbacks are not called twice even in dev mode + strict mode because the entire point of those callbacks is to perform side-effects.
> >
> > Note that I also observed that the reducer you pass to React.useReducer is not called twice in dev mode. I'm not sure why this is because I feel like that could also benefit from this kind of warning.

As seen above, this behavior is included to help you find bugs in your code. Since the updater functions should be idempotent and pure, running them twice instead of once should have no effect on your app's functionality. If it does, then that's a bug in your code.

It sounds like the `map.removeOverlays()` method you're calling is an effectful function, so it should not be called within a state updater function. I can see why you've implemented it this way based on the answers to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152888/how-to-read-and-modify-a-state-in-useeffect-iaw-exhaustive-deps-lint-rule), but I think using chitova263's answer would remedy this issue.

Comment: Wow, one of the best answers I’ve gotten on here including reading my older post. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I implemented the reducer and low and behold it also runs twice. From researching it, it seems it can also be run twice and reducers should also be pure (which mine is not). Which leaves me at a loss for my other question. I either don't put all my dependencies in or I have a reducer / setState that isn't pure. I posted that code in an edit.

Comment: @Diesel Yes, the reducer should be pure. chitova263's answer to your other question showed how you can accomplish what you were asking about, using a pure reducer. All of the impure code should be inside the `setEffect()` callback. The reducer in your example sandbox is pure (aside from the `console.log`s). Can you show us what your actual code looks like, with the impure reducer?

Comment: Since this doesn't really apply to this question I'll move over to the other question. I appreciate the help. I modified that question with an edit that explains the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152888/how-to-read-and-modify-a-state-in-useeffect-iaw-exhaustive-deps-lint-rule

Comment: Some of this is dead wrong as of React 18, in particular: "Note that useEffect and useLayoutEffect callbacks are not called twice even in dev mode + strict mode"

Answer (score 0):

I am running this piece of code and the useEffect() is getting called initially once by default at component mounting?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ChangeDOMTitle = (props) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Updating the count");
        document.title = `Clicked ${count} times`;
    });

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <input type="text" value={name}
             onChange={event => setName(event.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Clicked {count} times</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default ChangeDOMTitle;
```