# API called twice while useEffect triggered once. ReactJS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, rest

i am building a project, in which when user click the buyNow button in `Basket (child 2)` it will pass the props back to parent where it further pass it to another child in `Signin(child 3)` where we call an `API` call`(inside useEffect)` to update the mysql database but it seems that the `API call` is `called twice` as in `database two records` are being created and in front end i got two identical invoices record but different file names.

Any suggestion guys why i am facing this, please note if i remove the `useEffect` statement from the `Signin` it will then continuously non-stop call the `API call` so i think i cant remove the `useEffect`, other then this i cant see why it is happening. any suggestion please.

```
Main (APP)___|
             |_Child 1(Home)
             |_Child 2 (Basket)
             |_Child 3 (signin)(API triggers here)---Sub Child 3-1 (useraccount)
```

**Update-1:** After removing the `strictMode` it does solve the issue, but does it means if i temporarily fixed the issue or if i have to use the stricMode and find the real problem

- **Child 2- Basket**- Customer press the buyNow button and it triggers resetBasket function

```
     const buyNow = (basketItems) => {
      resetBasket(basketItems);
         window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/signin";
      };
    
     <ButtonGroup aria-label="quantityofproduct">
                        <Button variant="secondary" name="subtract" value="subtract" onClick={() => buyNow(basketItems)}>
                          Buy Now
                        </Button>
                      </ButtonGroup>
```

- **Main App**   resetBasket takes the basketitems and pass to parent element

```
      const [finalBuy, setfinalBuy] = useState(finalbuyitems());
    
    
    
    
     const resetBasket = (basketItems) => {
       setfinalBuy(basketItems);
        window.localStorage.setItem("user-final", JSON.stringify(basketItems));
    }
    
    
    
     <Route
                  path="/basket"
                  exact
                  render={(props) => (
                    <Basket {...props} userData={userData} userstatus={siginalready} basketItems={basketItems} updatedBasket={updatedBasket} resetBasket={resetBasket} />
                  )}
                />
    
    
     <Route
                  path="/signin"
                  exact
                  render={(props) => <Signin {...props} buyNow={buyNow} resetBuynow={resetBuynow} userData={userData} finalBuy={finalBuy} userstatus={siginalready} />}
                />
```

- **Child 3 - Signin**  ,here we call the `API call(using useEffect)` and update the Mysql server and recieve the invoice in `PDf` format from backend

```
  const [allInvoices, setallInvoices] = useState([]);

// The API call in the useEffect is triggering twice and thats why i am getting two invoices and two record at backend

  useEffect(() => {

 const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("content-type", "application/json");
const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers,
      credentials: "include",
      body: JSON.stringify(),
    };

    const newRequest = new Request("http://localhost:5000/api/invoice-all", options);

    (async () => {
      const invoiceFetch = await fetch(newRequest)
        .then((data) => {
 return data.json();
        })
        .then((data1) => {
 setallInvoices(data1);
        })
        .catch();
    })();
  // }, []);
 return <div>{userstatus ? <Useraccount userinfo={userData} userstatus={userstatus} finalBuy={finalBuy} allInvoices={allInvoices} /> : <SigninOptions />}</div>;
```

- **Sub Child-Useraccount** then it display the items recieved from the backend-mysql nodejs

```
     // here the return is showing two different invoices of same items bought i.e two times the API is being called
    return (
    allInvoices.map((eachInvoice, index) => {
    ........................................})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the  `<React.StrictMode>` is causing double execution. Please take a look after removing it from your top level component.
Please refer [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305074/react-strictmode-setstate-function-in-useeffect-is-run-multiple-times-when-effe) for more details on StrictMode double execution.

Comment: Thanks Rajeev, thats interesting i am just going through that link it mentions that useEffect is not affected by this stictMode,and as my API call is happening inside this useEffect .But when i delete the strict Mode it doesnt show twice so it looks fine, but does it means that we actually resolved the issue or if we have to use the strictmode and find another solution to this.