# useEffect in React runs in an infinite loop, when an array is passed as a dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, state, react-hooks

When the following code is run in a React component, it causes an endless loop. Why does passing an array as a dependency to `useEffect` (in this case, `args`), cause that to happen? How can I stop the endless loop from happening? The code should only run once.

I've read that I can use `[args.length]` to stop this from happening, but then the ESLint rule `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` throws an error, so I want to avoid doing it that way.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const args = ['a'];
  const [value, setValue] = useState(['b']);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(['c']);
  }, [args]);

  console.log('value', value);
}
```

Notice in the code above, that I don't even use or modify `args` at all, in the `useEffect` callback.

If I change the value of `args` to a string, like `const args = 'a'`, then there is no endless loop. So the problem seems to occur when the dependency is an array.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you want?
Your code can be ran only one time since args isn't changed anymore.
Let me know your purpose so I can help you.

Comment: @Shildra I want the code to only run once, but it's run in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `useRef` fixed this issue for me:

```js
const args = useRef(['a']);
const [value, setValue] = useState(['b']);

useEffect(() => {
  setValue(['c']);
}, [args]);

console.log('value', value);
```

And the value of `args` can be used within the `useEffect` callback, with `args.current`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that any change to `args` will cause your effect to run. At which point you `setValue(args)` so `args` changes again. This will cause your effect to run again... hence an infinite loop.

If you set `args` to the same string it was before it will not be registered as a change if they match per the way react detects changes. This will not work for an array or an object. `{test: 'a'} !== {test: 'a'}` and `['a'] !== ['a']` but `'a' === 'a'` and `1 === 1`.

I also ran into your problem. I ended up disabling the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule. But I have more data for you. I struggled to try to use this rule for a while.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152888/how-to-read-and-modify-a-state-in-useeffect-iaw-exhaustive-deps-lint-rule) I made is very similar to your question. The end result is you should use `setState` as a function (ie. `setState(oldState => oldState)` from your example) at which point the old state doesn't need to be a dependency or `useReducer` which also produces the same effect.

However, neither of these are likely pure with what you may be trying to do which creates more problems as seen in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305074/react-strictmode-setstate-function-in-useeffect-is-run-multiple-times-when-effe) I made later. If they are pure, you are fine.

The 4th solution on the [1st post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152888/how-to-read-and-modify-a-state-in-useeffect-iaw-exhaustive-deps-lint-rule) describes how you can aggressively avoid this problem, but ultimately I decided to use the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule and disable it line by line when I intentionally delete dependencies I don't want. I don't agree it should it be a rule after all this.

The problem you are trying to do is balance React's requirement that `useState` and `useReducer` are pure with the requirement for exhaustive deps. I think this leads to a lot of work to make these requirements happy over actual productivity.