# useEffect infinite loop with dependency array on redux dispatch

Tags: redux, react-hooks, use-effect, redux-toolkit

Running into an infinite loop when I try to dispatch an action which grabs all recent posts from state.

I have tried the following in useEffect dependency array

- `Object.values(statePosts)`
- `useDeepCompare(statePosts)`
- passing `dispatch`
- omitting `dispatch`
- omitting `statePosts`
- passing `statePosts`
- doing the same thing in `useCallback`

a lot of the suggestions came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

I have verified that data correctly updates in my redux store.

I have no idea why this is still happening

**my component**

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user)
  const { logs: statePosts } = useSelector((state) => state.actionPosts)

  const useDeepCompare = (value) => {
    const ref = useRef()
    if (!_.isEqual(ref.current, value)) {
      ref.current = value
    }
    return ref.current
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getActionLogsRest(user.email))
  }, [user, dispatch, useDeepCompare(stateLogs)])
```

**actionPosts createSlice**

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'actionPosts',

  initialState: {
    posts: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    postsLoading: (state, { payload }) => {
      if (state.loading === 'idle') {
        state.loading = 'pending'
      }
    },
    postsReceived: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.posts = payload
    },
  },
})

export default slice.reducer

const { postsReceived, postsLoading } = slice.actions

export const getActionPostsRest = (email) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch(postsLoading())
    const { data } = await getUserActionPostsByUser({ email })
    dispatch(postsReceived(data.userActionPostsByUser))
    return data.userActionPostsByUser
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove dispatch from dependencies.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getActionLogsRest(user.email))
  }, [user, dispatch, useDeepCompare(stateLogs)])
```

you cannot use hook as dependency and by the way, ref.current, is always undefined here

```
const useDeepCompare = (value) => {
    const ref = useRef()
    if (!_.isEqual(ref.current, value)) {
      ref.current = value
    }
    return ref.current
  }
```

because useDeepCompare essentially is just a function that you initiate (together with ref) on each call, all it does is just returns `value`. That's where the loop starts.

Comment: removing dispatch from dep array does not fix the issue

Comment: yeah, you need to remove circular dependency. What does `dispatch(getActionLogsRest(user.email))`? Updates logs? Then do a proper compare of `stateLogs`.  I would suggest useMemo for that.

Comment: fetches logs from api. would u recommend doing the compare in the action? reducer? useEffect?

Comment: Without knowing much about your code, I would suggest trying `useMemo` hook first. Something like this `const boolean = useMemo(()=>{deepCompare(stateLogs)},[stateLogs])` Put ref outside `deepCompare()` function. Or lift it up to global state.

Comment: Then pass result to `useEffect` dependencies, `[user, boolean]`

Comment: `boolean` could be any value really, but whenever it changes useEffect will trigger

Comment: it says I can't call hooks inside `useMemo` . unless `deepCompare` in your above comment is a function that is not part of my code

Comment: yes, just rename useDeepCompare to deepCompare and use it as regular function, move ref `const ref = useRef()` outside that function.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that on every change in `stateLogs` `useMemo` will run. A proper alternative would require you listen and compare to object fields, not the whole object. Like timestamp for example.

Comment: Could u elaborate on the timestamp solution?

Comment: If you logs have timestamps, you can access it and pass the latest one to useEffect as milliseconds. If it is a new one, render will happen. You obviously will have to  parse through logs, collect timestamps and then sort them but that will be faster than comparing 2 large objects anyway.