# Table not displaying the json values

Tags: reactjs, loops, jsx

The table is creating the fields that are seeing in the json url
PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD,BSJF,MONY
It sees 6 symbols and it creates 6 cells. 1 cell for each symbol
It knows the are 6 symbols but it does not want to display the values

Where is the issue?
Please help

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';


const App = props => {
 
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValues] = useState({});

  

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch("https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD,BSJF,MONY&types=stats,quote&token=");
     res
       .json()
       .then(res => setValues(res))
       .catch(err => setErrors(err));
   }
   console.log(quote);
   fetchData();
   }, []);
  const quote = Object.keys(value).map(i => value[i]);
  const columns = [
   
    {
      dataField: 'id', 
      text: 'Id'
    }, {
    
    
    dataField: 'Symbol', 
    text: 'Symbol'
  }, {
    dataField: 'price',
    text: 'Price'
  }, {
    dataField: 'CompanyName',
    text: 'Company Name'
  }];
  return (


    

    <div>
     <BootstrapTable keyField= "id" data={quote} columns={columns} />
     
    </div>


    


  );


}

export default App;
```

[image: It creates the fields for each stock but is not displaying]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite loop in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

Comment: Don't use an async function and then `then.catch` that just hurts my eyes

Comment: Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and coul

Comment: heyitsmarcucu @heyitsmarcucu
can you please provide the answer for this one?

Answer (score 1):

Well friend, you're in luck. This is a super easy fix. The error is in your useEffect, the second parameter should be an array. If you only want the useEffect to run when the component is initially rendered, it should be an empty array.

A link to the useEffect documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

It also looks like there is an issue with your fetch call, so you might want to look into that next as it's producing an error.

Lastly, the console.log(value) is not going to log the result as the setPlanets function is asynchronous. Try console logging 'res' and 'err' from within the .then and .catch functions, respectively.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';

const App = () => {
 
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [value, setPlanets] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD,BSJF,MONY&types=stats,quote&token=");
      res
        .json()
        .then(res => setPlanets(res))
        .catch(err => setErrors(err));
    }
    console.log(value);
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  const quote = Object.keys(value).map(i => value[i]);
  const columns = [{
    dataField: 'symbol',
    text: 'Symbol'
  }, {
    dataField: 'price',
    text: 'Price'
  }, {
    dataField: 'CompanyName',
    text: 'Company Name'
  }];
  return (
    <div>
     <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ quote } columns={ columns } />
    </div>
  );


}

export default App;
```

Comment: thanks, I updated the error: "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Comment: It's a warning, but each item you return in the map function should have a 'key' field as well. you could set it to 'key=id' in this case

Comment: Encountered two children with the same key, [object Object]. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and coul

Comment: Easiest solution is to set the key equal to the index, which is the second argument in the map function

Answer (score 1):

On useEffect you need to pass `[]` to execute once or add a dependencie `[something]`

```
useEffect(() => {
 async function fetchData() {
 const res = await fetch("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD,BSJF,MONY&types=stats,quote&token=");
  res
    .json()
    .then(res => setPlanets(res))
    .catch(err => setErrors(err));
}
console.log(value);
fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: thanks, I updated the error:  "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: Your data has the key `id` with a value integer?

Comment: Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and coul