# Infinite rerendering with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to rerender a component once the state is changed, this how I do it:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I am rerendering")
    const displayNotebook = async () => {
    const reponse = await axios({// URL etc...},
      });
      setItems(reponse.data); // add data to the list
    };

   displayNotebook()
  
  },[items]);
```

I pass the date in a map as so

```
const workspaceCard = items.map((msg) => (
<WorkspaceContent
  message={msg.content}
/>));
```

The problem is that the component is in a infinite rerendering, I could use an empty array but this not what I want, I am trying to rerender the component each time the state is updated.

I searched and found this answer [Infinite loop in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect) but does not help me

Comment: You need to revise your logic, you are triggering an effect to update items whenever items get updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gaëtan already indicated, your logic has a loop: inside your effect you are setting items, but you are also indicating that the effect should re-run whenever items change. Hence the cycle. The fix is simple then, just remove the dependency on `items`, if you don't need/want to rerun the effect whenever they change:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ...
  },[]);  // items removed
```