# Infinite loop on componentdidupdate with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-effect

I'm using redux and trying to fetch data when my component did update.
I'm using **useEffect** hook to track posts update and getting the state with useSelector.
I'm having issues as the component is making infinite fetching requests instead of a single request.
Anyone knows how I can stop it from making infinite requests
and make a single request if posts updated?

my code:

```
 const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts.posts);

 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts(page));
 }, [posts]);
```

[image showing infinite fetching requests being made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpsDp.png)

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect. Either take out the [posts] dependency and replace with [ ] or add an "if" statement inside the useEffect to ensure it only dispatches for a certain condition

Comment: Hey, maybe you meant to listen to changes to the page variable instead? Currently your useEffect hook runs on every change to the posts variable, which should cause the infinite loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite loop in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) documentation

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` combined.

So, `dispatch(getPosts(page))` will be called on component mount as well when any of the dependency provided get changed, this will make an API request and fetch the posts of this `page`. Which will eventually update the `state.posts.posts` once the API is successful. As, the same `state.posts.posts` is given as dependency to the `useEffect` hook this will trigger the function to get executed again and the cycle goes on.

[image]

For example if you want to make the API call and fetch new posts when there's a change in the `page` you should provide `page` as dependency instead of `posts` as shown below

```
const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts.posts);

 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts(page));
 }, [page]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts.posts);

 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts(page));
 }, []);

const updateNeeded = useSelector((state) => state.posts.updateNeeded);

 useEffect(() => {
  if (updateNeeded) {
    dispatch(getPosts(page));
  }
 }, [updateNeeded]);
```

Change updateNeeded to true by a dispatch action when you want to fetch a new update, and when the update is fetched dispatch an action which will make this flag to false again.