# How to use window.open() within useEffect hook in React without an infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new to React, Redux and Typescript. I am trying to implement SSO and OAuth like described [here](https://medium.com/swlh/create-a-react-app-with-typescript-redux-and-oauth-2-0-7f62d57890df). I was able to do it with a login button, so after clicking, it redirects to my app (if parameters are correct). However, I would like to have the process starting automatically while opening a page. (without any additional button). I assume that I can use *useEffect*. This is my code, but it creates an infinite loop.
What would be the proper way of removing infinite loop here?

```
export function Auth() {
    useEffect(() => {
       window.open(getAuthorizeHref(), "_self");
        
    }, []);

    return <div />;
}
```