# React JS useEffect hook send infinite no of request if i add an dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, react-router, react-hooks

**i have made an API in Django for fetching the TODO list tasks in my React JS Application but when i use allTasks of useState in dependency array of useEffect Hook then it starts sending endless get requests. I can't understand how is this happening also if i leave the dependency array empty then it works fine but then i have to refresh the page manually if some data changes in background.**

*Here below is the code of Tasklist.js Component*

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'   
import Task from './Task'

function TaskList() { 
    async function getAllTasks(url){
        let resp = await axios.get(url);  
        let all_tasks= await resp.data   
        return all_tasks;
    }
    const [allTasks, setAllTasks]= useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
        async function appendTasks(){
            let alltasks= await getAllTasks('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/retrieve')
            setAllTasks(alltasks)
        }
        appendTasks()
    },[allTasks])
    return (
        <div className="TaskList">
            {
                allTasks.map(function(task){ 
                    return( 
                        <Task key={task.id} task={task} /> 
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default TaskList
```

Comment: The useeffect hook will run every time one of the marked dependecies will change. So in that case remove the allTasks from the dependency array

Comment: Add `some data changes in background` in the dependencies instead `allTasks`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite loop in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

Comment: @im_baby no it doesn't

Comment: @OliverIlmjärv but if i remove allTasks from dependency array then it will not update automatically.. if the tasks changes

Comment: You are causing the infinite loop because you are saying "whenever this data changes: update this data". You can't both set state in the useEffect and trigger the useEffect when state changes.

Answer (score 1):

You got an infinite loop because you're modifying your `useEffect` dependency in the `useEffect` itself.

Remove your dependency to solve your problem :

```
useEffect(()=>{
    async function appendTasks(){
        let alltasks= await getAllTasks('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/retrieve')
        setAllTasks(alltasks)
    }
    appendTasks()
},[])
```

Remove the dependency. If you want to refresh your data you can, for example, set an interval to call your backend every interval of time.

```html
useEffect(()=>{
    async function appendTasks(){
        let alltasks= await getAllTasks('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/retrieve')
        setAllTasks(alltasks)
    }
    const interval = setInterval(() => appendTasks(), 30000) // 30000ms = 30 secondes
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
},[])
```

Here you will refresh your tasks every 30 secondes.

There is of course other options depending of your needs.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all - useEffect is run everytime its dependencies change, in this case its because you specify `allTasks` as dependency and in `useEffect` itself you call `setAllTasks` which changes `allTasks` so `useEffect` is called again, so `setAllTasks` is called again, so `allTasks` is changed and useEffect called again, and so on... I hope you understand now why you are getting infinite number of calls. Now solution - you don't really need `allTasks` dependency in this case - `setAllTasks` is enough - why ? because nowhere in `useEffect` you use `allTasks` variable.

Solution:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        async function appendTasks(){
            let alltasks= await getAllTasks('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/retrieve')
            setAllTasks(alltasks)
        }
        appendTasks()
    },[setAllTasks]) // notice the change here
```

2nd - not related to question, but you should include all dependencies in useEffect dependency array - in this case function `getAllTasks` should be included as well - but this would make infinite number of calls again - i suggest you to read something about useMemo and useCallback, but easiest solution for you should be something like this

```
useEffect(()=> {
    async function getAllTasks(url){
      let resp = await axios.get(url);  
      let all_tasks= await resp.data   
      return all_tasks;
    }
    let response = await getAllTasks('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/retrieve')
    setAllTasks(response)    
}, [setAllTasks])
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need to replace in your code is useEffect dependency array
"allTasks" with "addTodos"
eg: const [addTodos, setAddTodos]= useState([])

Note: look at the below snippet to get an idea

import {useState } from "react";
import GetTodoList from "./GetTodoList";

export default function AddTodo() {

```
const [input, setInput]= useState("");
const [addTodos, setAddTodos]= useState([])

const setInputValue =(e)=>{
    setInput(e.target.value)
}

const addToLocalStorage=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setAddTodos([...addTodos, {"task": input}])
    localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(addTodos))
}

return (
    <div>
        <input value={input} onChange={setInputValue} type="text" />
        <button onClick={addToLocalStorage}>Add addTodos</button>
        <GetTodoList addTodos={addTodos}/>
    </div>
)
```

}

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function GetTodoList({addTodos}) {

```
const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([])

const getTodo=()=>{
    const result = localStorage.getItem("todo");
    setTodoList(JSON.parse(result))
    //setTotos(JSON.parse(result))
}

useEffect(() => {
    getTodo();
}, [addTodos]) //addTodos as dependency, when the setAddTodos updates then useEffect recalls getTodo() with out hard refresh 
return (
    <div>
      {(todoList)?
        todoList.map(todo=><p>{todo.task}</p>) : ""}
    </div>
)
```

}

export default GetTodoList