# Issue with infite fetch loop using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am having an issue with fetching data inside an useEffect().
I can see in the developer tool, that the fetch is called in an infite loop.

I am quite new to React, so maybe this is a simple issue. I have tried looking up others with same issues, but can't seem to make a connection with my code.

Code is below.

```
export function Category(){
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://localhost:5001/api/Category')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => 
            setCategories(data));
        return () => {
            
        }
    })

    const renderCategories  = (cats) => {
        return (
        <Table ClassName= "mt-4" striped bordered hoved size= "=sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> Id: </th>
                    <th> Category Name: </th>
                    <th> Options </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {cats.map(cats=>
                    <tr key = {cats.categoryId}> 
                    <td> {cats.categoryId}</td>
                    <td> {cats.name}</td>
                </tr>)}                           
            </tbody>
        </Table>
        )
    }
    return(
        <div>
            {renderCategories(categories)}               
        </div>
    )    
}
```

Comment: The last line of your useEffect block, `})`, needs to be `}, [])` (i.e. an empty dependency array will ensure the function only runs once instead of each time the state changes)

Comment: Please read the useEffect docs

Comment: useEffect is called on every render (unless you use an empty dependency array) and setState will trigger a rerender, causing your endless loop.

Comment: First [google result](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+hooks+load+data+from+api+infinite+loop+site%3Astackoverflow.com&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=AOaemvKOXKUOMWy4dgGtKpW1RxUnnbNTUQ%3A1632990065066&ei=cXNVYbagA76B9u8P8YKTiAs&oq=react+hooks+load+data+from+api+infinite+loop+site%3Astackoverflow.com) is the dupe: [Infinite loop in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` is called whenever `state` changes. In your code, you call `setCategories` inside `useEffect` to change the `categories` state. That action triggers the `useEffect` itself in an infinite loop.

This is a common issue for new people who learn React 17 with hooks or even former React Class developers. To avoid this, using square bracket `[]` like @Chris G is okay for now but it isn't a good practice when scaling because you just *tricks* React to runs `useEffect` once.

Dan Abramov recommends using `useReducer` to manage state outside of `useEffect`.
This is his excellent article that explains every corner of `useEffect`. Let's pour some coffee and read it because it's as long as a book: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/