# Can't stop an infinite loop at nested component at useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to curb useEffect related to nested components. Here are the components:
**Parent** *(it receives data from API)****:***

```
const ListOfLots = (props) => {
  const initial = {listLots: props.lots, form: props.form}
  const [lots, setLots] = useState(initial);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLots({
      listLots: props.lots,
      form: props.form
    });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {
        lots.listLots.map(function(lot) {
          return <Lot key={lot.uuid} lot={lot} procForm={lots.form}/>
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Nested:**

```
const Lot = (props) => {
  const initial = {currLot: props.lot, form: props.form};
  const [lot, setLot] = useState(initial);
  let getWinningBid = (offers) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < offers.length; i++) {
      console.log("BOOM!!!");
      if (offers[i].isTrue === true) {
        return offers[i].pip;
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

While I am using no dependencies at parent's `useEffect`, I have got an infinite invoking of `console.log("BOOM!!!")`, that is, of course, unacceptable, but my **Nested** component rerendered. When I try to use the following type of dependencies at `useEffect`: `[]`, `[lots.form]`, `[lots.listLots]` or `[lots.listLots.length]` my **Nested** component is not rerendered: it stays blank. So the result is the following: I have an infinite `useEffect` loop or not-working(?) `useEffect`.
Is there any way in this case to handle the `useEffect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLots({
      listLots: props.lots,
      form: props.form
    });
  }, [props.lots, props.form]);
```

This triggers the callback only if the value of props.lots, props.form is changed else it won't be triggered on every rerender as in case of no second argument.

A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect) might help you find better explanations.