# ReactJS - use localStorage as a dependency for useEffect causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, infinite-loop, use-effect

This code give me infinite loop at line `console.log`

```
const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_info"));
const [filterSemester, setFilterSemester] = useState(SEMESTERS[0]);
const [scoreData, setScoreData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, [userInfo, filterSemester]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("scoreData: ", scoreData);
}, [scoreData]);

const getData = () => {
  const params = {
    student_id: userInfo?.student_info?.id,
    school_year_id:
      userInfo?.student_info?.class_info?.grade_info?.school_year_id,
    semester: filterSemester.key,
  };
  getStudyInfoBySchoolYear(params).then((res) => {
    if (res?.status === 200) {
      setScoreData(res?.data?.data);
    }
  });
};
```

If I remove `userInfo` from the dependency array of the first `useEffect`, the loop will gone, I wonder why? I didn't change it at all in the code.

Comment: It's happening because when you print the values in the console from 2nd useEffect then the first one also re triggers.

Comment: Try to manage them in one useEffect with use of if statements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite loop in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userInfo` is actually changing.

It is a functional component, so all the code that is inside the component will run on every render, thus, `userInfo` gets re-created on every render, because it was not declared as a reference (with `useRef`) or, more commonly, as a state (with `useState`).

The flow is as follows:

1. The component mounts.
2. The first `useEffect` runs `getData`. The second `useEffect` also runs.
3. `getData` will update `scoreData` state with `setScoreData`. This latter will trigger a re-render, and also `scoreData` has changed, so the second `useEffect` will run.
4. When the render takes place, all the code within your component will run, including the `userInfo` declaration (creating a new reference to it, unless `localStorage.getItem("user_info")` is returning `undefined`).
5. React detects `userInfo` as changed, so the first `useEffect` will run again.
6. The process repeats from **step 3**.

You could replace your

```
const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_info"));
```

with

```
  const userInfo = React.useRef(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_info")));
```

and your

```
useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, [userInfo, filterSemester]);
```

with

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [userInfo.current, filterSemester]);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_info"));
const [filterSemester, setFilterSemester] = useState(SEMESTERS[0]);
const [scoreData, setScoreData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, [localStorage.getItem("user_info"), filterSemester]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("scoreData: ", scoreData);
}, [scoreData]);

const getData = () => {
  const params = {
    student_id: userInfo?.student_info?.id,
    school_year_id:
      userInfo?.student_info?.class_info?.grade_info?.school_year_id,
    semester: filterSemester.key,
  };
  getStudyInfoBySchoolYear(params).then((res) => {
    if (res?.status === 200) {
      setScoreData(res?.data?.data);
    }
  });
};
```