# React fetch API keep requesting on loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
function getCharacter(){
    fetch("http://localhost:8001/tinder-card").then((resp)=>resp.json()).then((result)=>{
        if(result.status==false){
            alert("No card found in database")
        }
        else{
            setpeople(result)
        }
        
    })
}


useEffect(()=>{
    getCharacter();
})
```

This is my react code where I am fetching user data from the node API everything is working fine but when I see my browser network tab fetch API is keep requesting on a loop and this is making my computer freeze. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty array as the second argument of `useEffect()`.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    getCharacter();
}, [])
```

Otherwise `useEffect` will run every time your component re-renders causing this infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to pass deps as [].

```
React.useEffect(() => {
     fetch("http://localhost:8001/tindercard").then((resp)=>resp.json()).then((result)=>{
               if(result.status==false){
                   alert("No card found in database")
               }
               else{
                   setpeople(result)
               }
               
           })
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an empty array as a second argument for useEffect, maybe your question is duplicated **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect)**

```
useEffect(()=>{
getCharacter();
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to define an fetch API in react.

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);

async function getPro() {
    await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products?limit=7")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setProduct(data.products);
        });
}

useEffect(() => {
    getPro();
}, []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).