# useEffect cause infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop

This is my product count code, by calling *+ button*, it will add product object to the list of **selectedFoods** state; and decrease the amount of the products by calling *- button*.

I face an infinite loop when I want to remove the product item which has an amount of zero; by filtering this object from list of selected products leads to problem.

Here is what causes the problem

```
    if (newFood.amount < 1) {
        setSelectedFoods((prevFoods) => {
          return prevFoods.filter((food) => food.id !== newFood.amount.id);
        });
      }
```

How can I prevent this?

```
export const FoodContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [selectedFoods, setSelectedFoods] = useState([]);
  const [newFood, setNewFood] = useState({});
  const [mode, setMode] = useState(null);
  const [length, setLength] = useState(selectedFoods.length);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mode === "add") {
      const duplicate = selectedFoods.some((item) => item.id === newFood.id);
      if (duplicate) {
        selectedFoods.forEach((item) => {
          if (item.id === newFood.id) {
            item.amount = newFood.amount;
          }
        });
      } else {
        setSelectedFoods((prevFoods) => {
          return [...prevFoods, newFood];
        });
      }
    } else {
      selectedFoods.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.id === newFood.id) {
          item.amount = newFood.amount;
        }
      });
      if (newFood.amount < 1) {
        setSelectedFoods((prevFoods) => {
          return prevFoods.filter((food) => food.id !== newFood.amount.id);
        });
      }
    }
    console.log(selectedFoods);
  }, [newFood, mode, selectedFoods, setSelectedFoods]);

  const selectingFood = (food) => {
    setLength((pre) => pre + 1);
    setNewFood(food.newFoodItem);
    setMode(food.mode);
  };

  return (
    <FoodContext.Provider
      value={{
        foodItems: foodItem,
        selectingFood: selectingFood,
        selectedFoods: selectedFoods,
        selectedItemLength: length,
      }}
    >
      {props.children} {/* App componnet */}
    </FoodContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite loop in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues with that `useEffect` (and some question about whether it should be an effect at all; more on that below):

1. You're using `selectedFoods` as a dependency, but calling `setSelectedFoods` in the effect. That's what causes the infinite loop.
2. You're modifying objects in `selectedFoods` instead of creating a new objects, which breaks the primary rule of state: Don't directly modify state items. [More in the docs](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state).
3. You're modifying state based on existing state, but the existing state could be stale.
4. Harmless, but: there's never any need to list `useState` state setter functions like `setSelectedFoods` in dependency arrays; they're guaranteed to be stable for the lifetime of the component instance.

Instead, pass a callback into `setSelectedFoods` so it calls your code with the up-to-date array. Then you don't need the array as an effect dependency, and you're never working with a stale copy. Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (mode === "add") {
        // *** Using the callback form, we don't have a dependency on `selectedFoods` anymore
        setSelectedFoods((selectedFoods) => {
            const duplicate = selectedFoods.some(
                (item) => item.id === newFood.id
            );
            if (duplicate) {
                // *** Creating a new array
                return selectedFoods.map((item) => {
                    if (item.id === newFood.id) {
                        // *** Creating a new object
                        item = { ...item, amount: newFood.amount };
                    }
                    return item;
                });
            } else {
                setSelectedFoods((prevFoods) => {
                    return [...prevFoods, newFood];
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        // *** Again, using the callback form
        setSelectedFoods((selectedFoods) => {
            if (newFood.amount < 1) {
                return selectedFoods.filter(
                    (food) => food.id !== newFood.amount.id
                );
            } else {
                // *** Creating a new array
                return selectedFoods.map((item) => {
                    if (item.id === newFood.id) {
                        // *** Creating a new object
                        item = { ...item, amount: newFood.amount };
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}, [newFood, mode]);
```

Now the effect is only triggered when `newFood` or `mode` changes.

But stepping back: It seems very odd to have an *effect* adding and removing items from your `selectedFoods` array. That seems like something that should be happening as a direct action, not as an effect, though of course it's hard to say without a broader context.

Comment: thanks a milion , you solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

You shouldnt add a lot of dependencies on useEffect, break it to multiple useEffect and verify