# Strange loop in my useEffect by adding auth as dependence

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I had a question regarding my react code of a dasbhord because it makes a quite strange loop. I tried to solve it by removing the `auth`  variable from the `useEffect` dependency. And it works only it seems a bit dirty not putting the dependency because even during the build react complains that it is not entered as a dependency. Does anyone have any idea if there is an error in the code or if there is another solution

```js
const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const[serviceAvailable, setServiceAvailable] = useState(1);
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState({
    displayed: false,
    header: "",
    text: "",
    success: false,
    warn: false,
    danger: false,
    info: false,
  });

  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);

  let subdomain = window.location.host.split(".")[0];

  //subdomain = "admin";

  useEffect(() => {
    const getServiceAvailability = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.domain.com/service/status/dashboard`
      );
      const json = await response.json();
      return json.status;
    };

    const Login = async () => {
      const serviceStatus = await getServiceAvailability();
      if(serviceStatus === 0){
        setServiceAvailable(0);
        return;
      }

      const isLogin = QueryParamUtil.GetValueOf("token");
      if (isLogin) return setIsLoading(false);

      const token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");

      if (!token) return (window.location.href = Consts.API_LOGIN);

      **UserAPI.UserLogin(token, subdomain === "admin").then((logged) => {
        if (logged.user) {
          auth.Login(logged.user, logged.canteen);
          setIsLoading(false);
        } else return (window.location.href = logged.location);
      });**

      
    };
    Login();
  }, [**auth**, subdomain]);


  if(serviceAvailable === 0) return <ServiceOffline />

  if (isLoading) return <LoadingPage />;


  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <HeaderComponent />
      {auth.User && <NavbarComponent subdomain={subdomain} />}
      {alert.displayed && (
        <AlertComponent
          alert={alert}
          setAlertStatus={setAlert}
        />
      )}
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/login"
          element={
            <LoginPage subDomain={subdomain} />
          }
        />
        <Route exact path="/" element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route
            path="*"
            element={subdomain === "admin" ? <RootAdmin /> : <RootDashboard setAlert={setAlert}/>}
          />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: modifying `auth` inside useEffect is causing it, the to create a hook for auth and don't use useEffect
look at this for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect

Comment: @ZhivkoNikolov so the only solution is to remove the auth dependence? In if yes how can I avoid the following react waring: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'auth'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps?