# How to dynamically assign data via useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form in React JS with some data that will have dynamic keys so I don't want to hardcode their assignment in setData. (Context: I want the form to contain these values when the form loads)

Basically, I have a map which maps all of my keys to their values. I am trying to do something along the lines of:

```js
// Keys and values held here. 
 myMap = Map<string, mixed>;
 
 const [data, setData] = useState(() => {
    const data = {
      submit: 0,
      // Set data that I know the keys of here.
    };
    // Set data that I don't know the keys of here.
    // I am trying to dynamically set data[key] as follows (which does not work):
    Object.keys(myMap).forEach(key => data[key] = myMap[key]);
    return data;
  });
```

Anyone know why this is not working / how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Is myMap a `props` coming from the parent?

Comment: @konekoya yes, myMap is passed via props

Comment: Is it a value obtained by an async operation like an HTTP get or something? If so, you will need to use `useEffect` to wait until the async value is loaded and update the state then

Comment: @konekoya no, I don't believe there are any issues in terms of that - I tried printing out the map on the line right before I try to set the values and it contains all of the info I expect it to

Comment: Okay, could you also include some data of that `myMap` variable?

Comment: @konekoya Yep here's a sample: [age: 20, language: "english", user: null, ...]

Comment: And you don't want to just accomplish this initial state setting in a component did mount (i.e. `useEffect( () => { do it here }, [] )`)?

Comment: Can you expand your example to include where the `Map` is created/updated and how it is being passed down? For one thing, that looks like an incorrect initalisation of `myMap` since it is usually called as `new Map()` - you can also call `myMap.keys()` directly. As a general note, it is usually a [bad idea to use Maps with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605759/react-setting-state-to-an-es6-map/53606339#53606339).