# How to use Map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have following state in my component:

```
const [map, setMap] = useState<Map<number,string>>(new Map())
```

My question is how to update it properly in React.

Should I use it like this:

```
map.set(1, "hi")
```

Or like this:

```
setMap(prev => {
   let newMap = prev
   newMap.set(1, "hi")
   return newMap
})
```

Or maybe there is an even better method?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605759/react-setting-state-to-an-es6-map) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method is definitely not the way to do so, since you are mutating the state. The second method can be used with a slight change:

```
setMap(prev => {
    const newMap = new Map(prev);
    newMap.set(1, "hi")
    return newMap
}
```

Here, you are duplicating the map into a new object, instead of referring to the original map reference.