# How does React.useEffect differentiate items in its second argument

Tags: reactjs

```
const [messageCount, setMessageCount] = useState(0)
const [username, setUsername] = useState('Andres')
...
useEffect(
  () => {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}, you have ${count} unread messages`)
  },
  [name, count]
)
```

In a scenario like the above, where the second argument of `useEffect` has more than one item, and they're basically values. How does it differentiate each item ?

if at a given time, `name = 'Andres'` and `count = 10`, and moments later `count = 20`

How does `useEffect` decide how to compare items:

`'Andres' === 10` or `10 === 20` ?

Comment: The answer is simple, If one of the dependencies has changed since the last time, the effect will run again. what do you want to know exactly?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I'm not asking what but how. I tried looking at the source code but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: It uses shallow equal check, are you looking for the method source code?

Comment: I think it is simple, but not what you said. It must use the order of the items to know what to compare them with in the next renders.

Comment: [How does shallow compare work in react](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36084515/3367974), also [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7837456/3367974)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is function called `areHookInputsEqual` in ReactFiberHooks.js in react-reconciler [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L312)

This function is called from updateEffectImpl if prev dependencies and next dependencies are equal react won't push effect so it won't run.

Comment: Amit, perfect. 

This is what i was looking for: 

  for (let i = 0; i < prevDeps.length && i < nextDeps.length; i++) {
    if (is(nextDeps[i], prevDeps[i])) {
      continue;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;

Answer (score 0):

**How does useEffect decide how to compare items**

in this case use effect will be called if value  of name or count will change,that is name will not be compared to count but it will be compared to its previous value.

(note: you have used name that should be username)