# Continuous Rendering even when value does not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

### Problem

My component renders every second instead of only rendering if the state passed into setCurrentlyPlaying() is different. How can I fix this behavior?

### Background

I would like to check an API every 1 second. Aside from the first render, I only want my component to rerender when the incomingSong differs from the currentlyPlayingSong. I'm banking on the State hook's ability to only trigger a rerender if the passed in state is different than the previous based on the Object.is comparison algorithm. Even if I only return(`<div></div>`); in my component it continues to render every 1 second, so it seems like the problem stems from this logic. I test this by playing NOTHING on my Spotify so it always goes into the first `if` statement and it still rerenders every second (prints the console.log("RENDERED") statement).

```
    const [currentlyPlayingSong, setCurrentlyPlayingSong] = useState({ type: 'Now Playing', name: 'No Song Playing', artists: [], imageUrl: ''});

    console.log("RENDERED")

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("initial effect including updateSongs");

        const updateSongs = async () => {
            const result = await getCurrentlyPlaying();

            var incomingSong = {};

            // no song is playing
            if(result.data === "") {
                incomingSong = { type: 'Now Playing', name: 'No Song Playing', artists: [], imageUrl: ''};
            }
            // some song is playing
            else {
                var songJSONPath = result.data.item;
                incomingSong = {
                    type: 'Now Playing', 
                    name: songJSONPath.name,
                    id: songJSONPath.id,
                    artists: songJSONPath.artists.map(artist => artist.name + " "),
                    imageUrl: songJSONPath.album.images[songJSONPath.album.images.length - 2].url,
                };
            }

            // console.log("currentlyPlayingSong: ", currentlyPlayingSong)
            // console.log("incomingSong: ", incomingSong);

            // this line!!!!
            setCurrentlyPlayingSong(incomingSong);
        }

        updateSongs();

        const timer = setInterval(updateSongs, 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(timer);
    },[]);
```

Comment: Console logging in the body of a functional component ***is not actually*** an accurate measure for how often a component is rendered ***to the DOM***, you should do this in an `useEffect` hook. Also, `updateSongs` creates a new `incomingSong` object reference each time it's invoked, and since react uses shallow reference equality it will trigger a rerender every time you `setCurrentlyPlayingSong(incomingSong);`. You should do this conditional check manually *before* updating state with a new value. How you determine equality between the objects is up to you. `id` seems a good choice.

Comment: @sj123 but you're always passing a new object to `setCurrentlyPlayingSong` so, there's no way React can understand that it got the same song.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console logging in the body of a functional component ***is not actually*** an accurate measure for how often a component is rendered ***to the DOM***, you should do this in an `useEffect` hook.

Also, `updateSongs` creates a new `incomingSong` object reference each time it's invoked, and since react uses shallow reference equality it will trigger a rerender every time you `setCurrentlyPlayingSong(incomingSong);`. You should do this conditional check manually *before* updating state with a new value. How you determine equality between the objects is up to you. `id` seems a good choice.

Check if the song `id` is different and only update state when it is *actually* a different song.

```
if (currentlyPlayingSong.id !== incomingSong.id) {
  setCurrentlyPlayingSong(incomingSong);
}
```

code

```
const [currentlyPlayingSong, setCurrentlyPlayingSong] = useState({ 
  type: 'Now Playing',
  name: 'No Song Playing',
  artists: [],
  imageUrl: '',
});

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("RENDERED"); // <-- logs when component is rendered to DOM
});

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("initial effect including updateSongs");

  const updateSongs = async () => {
    const result = await getCurrentlyPlaying();

    let incomingSong = {};

    // no song is playing
    if (result.data === "") {
      ...
    }
    // some song is playing
    else {
      ...
    }

    // check if song id is different and only update if true
    if (currentlyPlayingSong.id !== incomingSong.id) {
      setCurrentlyPlayingSong(incomingSong);
    }
  }

  updateSongs();

  const timer = setInterval(updateSongs, 1000);

  return () => clearInterval(timer);
},[]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not notice that it was a new object every time. It now works how I want it to. I ended up using the lodash _.isEqual() method. Also, didn't realize that console.log() outside the useEffect() is not accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a song's name indicates the identity of a song. You can add an if statement before updating the state.

```
if (currentlyPlayingSong.name !== incomingSong.name) {
 setCurrentlyPlayingSong(incomingSong);
}
```

This will make sure to update the state only when the song has changed. If `name` isn't the correct property to check then replace it with the correct one.

React has no way of understanding that it can prevent the state update as you're passing a new object every time. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36084515/9765167;) to know more about react compares different values.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. I didn't properly understand the equality.