# React button disabled property not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have trouble using the disabled property on a button with react. The property works if I hard code a value in the input but the button is not re-rendered automatically when the state is updated through an input change.

```
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ email: "" });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <form>
        <div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="email">
              Email
            </label>
          </div>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            placeholder=""
            onChange={(e) =>
              setUser((previous) => {
                previous.email = e.target.value;
                return previous;
              })
            }
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={user.email === ""}>
          Button
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem can be experienced live here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-kapitsa-z2zj3m?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Just set the user with value : `setUser({'email': e.target.value})`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
(e) => setUser((previous) => ({...previous, email: e.target.value}))
```

You trying to mutate the previous state manually is what prevents React from detecting a change (because the reference stays the same)

Also, to use control forms properly, you need to add this prop to your input:

```
value={user.email}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the mentioned code `previous` points to the same reference as the new state you are setting. For complex state variables like objects React finds diff of object using [shallow comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36084891/10140124) and since both variables point to the object there is no rerender.

Creating a copy of the object which points to a different address in memory, and setting the state using that should fix it.

```
 setUser((previous) => {
                const newValue = { ...previous };
                newValue.email = e.target.value;
                return newValue;
              })
```

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-cookies-5zrvg6?file=/src/App.js:620-793)

That is why it is never a good idea to mutate state in React. Always create a new copy and make changes to that. This is the base of pure functions and functional programming.